# He has been having headaches for the past ten days

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive, stative-verbs

What is the difference between:

1. He **has been having**  headaches for the past ten days.
2. He **has had**  headaches for the past ten days.

Is the main verb "have" of sentences (1) and (2) a *stative* verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. He has been having headaches for the past ten days.

This suggests to me that he had a number of separate headaches over the past ten days.

2. He has had a headache for the past ten days.

I would not use the second sentence as it appears in your question, but I would use it in the form shown above. This would mean that he has had one headache continuously for the whole ten days.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have), **have** meaning POSSESS is stative (it is marked "not continuous"), but **have** meaning BE ILL is not stative.

Comment: Just one more question: Is this sentence correct: *He **has had** headaches in the past few days?* If so, is there any difference between this sentence and sentence (1) in the OP?

Comment: **has had headaches** suggests that he has had at least two. **has been having headaches** suggests that they were more frequent than that, ie there must have been several.

Comment: Although I accepted your answer I still have doubts. You say: ***have** meaning BE ILL is not stative.* If that is the case, then would you say: *He **has been having** a headache for the past ten days.*

Comment: No, you wouldn't. present perfect is fine to describe a single situation that lasts until present: "He **has worked** here for 25 years". Present perfect continuous is only necessary if there are multiple, intermittent situations "he has been having headaches for the past ten days".